# Suitable Primary key type in oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design

What is the difference if we make primary key as

1. varchar2
2. byte[] <-18

How it will impact the searching in a table.

Comment: There is no data type `byte[]` in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

If you mean what is the difference between varchar2(18 char) or varchar2(18 byte), it won't mean anything from the perspective of the primary key.

If you define the field as VARCHAR2(18 BYTE), Oracle can use up to 18 bytes for storage, but you may not actually be able to store 18 characters in the field, because some of them take more than one byte to store, e.g. non-English characters, ascii extended characters.

In the primary key, an automatic unique index is associated to it. So, with a character set as UTF-8, an index might occupy more space when using char than byte. But, normally speaking, it will have no relation whatsoever with either using char or byte.

Keep in mind that if you use multibyte charactersets as UTF-8, then the space consumed by the data types will be greater when you use CHAR instead of BYTE as NLS_SEMANTICS.
So, the greater the storage, the bigger the index, then more time/cpu consuming when you access to it.

Hope it helps.
Regards

Comment: "*if you use CHAR as data type, it will consume 18 bytes no matter how many characters are in the field*" - not true. `char()` is subject to the NLS_CHAR_SEMANTICS the same way as `VARCHAR2`. If it's a multi-byte character set, a `char(18)` could use up to 72 bytes

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , char specifies a fixed-length character string. Oracle ensures that all values stored in a CHAR column have the length specified by size. If you insert a value that is shorter than the column length, then Oracle blank-pads the value to column length. VARCHAR2 specifies a variable-length character string. When you create a VARCHAR2 column, you supply the maximum number of bytes or characters of data that it can hold. Oracle subsequently stores each value in the column exactly as you specify it, provided the value does not exceed the column's maximum length of the column

Comment: Yes, CHAR is a fixed length type. But there is still the difference between `char(18 byte)` and `char(18 char)` - the latter might use up to 72 bytes depending on the databases character set

Comment: Of course, that is the difference between using ( for example UTF-8 ) , so a multibyte characterset , than not using it. What I was trying to explain is that I would always advise to use varchar2 rather than char, if possible.  Perhaps, I did not explain very well in my answer the difference between byte and char in a multibycharacter set .configuration

Comment: My point is, that the claim "*CHAR as data type, it will consume 18 byte*" as written, is simply not true (because it could be more bytes). Writing "CHAR as a data type will always consume 18 **characters**" would be the correct thing to say.

Comment: you are right. My explanation was not 100% accurate. You are right, in a multibyte characterset it will consume more than 18bytes if some of the characters are ascii extended.